# my computer lag after adding the option adjust for a tv for my duals screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, xrandr

Recently, I have add my tv as a second screen on my computer. The problem : I have checked the option "ajuster pour une tv" (adjust for a tv) for my tv screen.

[image]

But with this option, my computer lag so much that I can't uncheck the option. And if I withdraw my hdmi cable from my tv, I can't acces to the option of my tv screen.

So my question, can I uncheck this option with xrandr or directly in a config file ?

Comment: The option "adjust for TV" is only "necessary" to compensate for the oversacanning feature some TVs have. It's ALWAYS preferable to adjust to the proper screen size from the TV. As a matter of fact this option appeared only in the current Ubuntu release.

Comment: ok, but it's definitly this option that make my computer lag. How can I remove it without my tv connected ?

Comment: You can't. Connect the TV, disable the feature, adjust using the TV's own menus or remote, if necessary.

Comment: I can't disable the feature. When I connecte my tv,, my computer lag so much that it almost freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved my problem by installing nvidia drivers ... Not really what I wanted but it works ...